# How to apply a custom filtering function on a Spark DataFrame

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, filter, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame of the form:

```
A_DF = |id_A: Int|concatCSV: String|
```

and another one:

```
B_DF = |id_B: Int|triplet: List[String]|
```

Examples of `concatCSV` could look like:

```
"StringD, StringB, StringF, StringE, StringZ"
"StringA, StringB, StringX, StringY, StringZ"
...
```

while a `triplet` is something like:

```
("StringA", "StringF", "StringZ")
("StringB", "StringU", "StringR")
...
```

I want to produce the *cartesian* set of `A_DF` and `B_DF`, e.g.;

```
| id_A: Int | concatCSV: String                             | id_B: Int | triplet: List[String]            |
|     14    | "StringD, StringB, StringF, StringE, StringZ" |     21    | ("StringA", "StringF", "StringZ")|
|     14    | "StringD, StringB, StringF, StringE, StringZ" |     45    | ("StringB", "StringU", "StringR")|
|     18    | "StringA, StringB, StringX, StringY, StringG" |     21    | ("StringA", "StringF", "StringZ")|
|     18    | "StringA, StringB, StringX, StringY, StringG" |     45    | ("StringB", "StringU", "StringR")|
|    ...    |                                               |           |                                  |
```

Then keep just the records that have at least two *substrings* (e.g `StringA, StringB`) from `A_DF("concatCSV")` that appear in `B_DF("triplet")`, i.e. use `filter` to exclude those that don't satisfy this *condition*.

**First question is:** can I do this without converting the DFs into RDDs?

**Second question is:** can I ideally do the whole thing in the `join` step--as a `where` condition?

I have tried experimenting with something like:

```
val cartesianRDD = A_DF
   .join(B_DF,"right")
   .where($"triplet".exists($"concatCSV".contains(_)))
```

but `where` cannot be resolved. I tried it with `filter` instead of `where` but still no luck. Also, for some strange reason, type annotation for `cartesianRDD` is `SchemaRDD` and not `DataFrame`. How did I end up with that? Finally, what I am trying above (the short code I wrote) is incomplete as it would keep records with just one substring from `concatCSV` found in `triplet`.

So, **third question is**: Should I just change to RDDs and solve it with a custom filtering function?

Finally, **last question**: Can I use a custom filtering function with DataFrames?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Shouldn't the type of `triplet` be `List[(String, String, String)]`?

Comment: Also what version of Spark are you using?

Comment: Thanks, fixing it in the example - bad phrasing.I am using Spark 1.5.2

Comment: Turns out I was right to begin with List[String] that's how the type is declared in scala.

Comment: Typically if you know that a collection should have a fixed length it is best to use a tuple but it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `CROSS JOIN` is implemented in `Hive`, so you could first do the cross-join using `Hive SQL`:

```
A_DF.registerTempTable("a")
B_DF.registerTempTable("b")

// sqlContext should be really a HiveContext
val result = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM a CROSS JOIN b")
```

Then you can filter down to your expected output using two `udf`'s. One that converts your string to an array of words, and a second one that gives us the *length* of the *intersection* of the resulting array column and the existing column `"triplet"`:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val splitArr = udf { (s: String) => s.split(",").map(_.trim) }
val commonLen = udf { (a: WrappedArray[String], 
                       b: WrappedArray[String]) => a.intersect(b).length }

val temp = (result.withColumn("concatArr",
  splitArr(col("concatCSV"))).select(col("*"),
  commonLen(col("triplet"), col("concatArr")).alias("comm"))
  .filter(col("comm") >= 2)
  .drop("comm")
  .drop("concatArr"))

temp.show
+----+--------------------+----+--------------------+
|id_A|           concatCSV|id_B|             triplet|
+----+--------------------+----+--------------------+
|  14|StringD, StringB,...|  21|[StringA, StringF...|
|  18|StringA, StringB,...|  21|[StringA, StringF...|
+----+--------------------+----+--------------------+
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks!